# AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication analog for .net framework

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have several Web APIs, some implemented using .Net Core, others using the .NET framework.

I use AD and `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` to authenticate responses from one .NET Core service to another.

Can anyone tell me what the equivalent of `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` is for the .NET framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` is what you want. Here's the [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/main/TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L17) for asp.net web api.

But the easiest way should be integrating AAD when creating the api project. And you will get code like below:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                         ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                    },
                });
        }
```

[image]

I had a test in my side and here's the test result. I just added configurations for the AAD. In my `web.config` file, I have this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="ida:Tenant" value="tenant_id" />
      <add key="ida:TenantId" value="tenant_id" />
      <add key="ida:Audience" value="api://aad_client_id_used_exposing_api" />
      <add key="ida:ClientID" value="aad_client_id" />
      <add key="ida:AppKey" value="client_secret" />
      <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
      <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44321/" />
      <add key="ida:GraphUserUrl" value="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/" />
  </appSettings>
```

[image]

The token I generated by this request.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response. I will try it and get back with the result

Comment: thank you for your reply, you may add the `App.config` file manually following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/read-app-settings).

Comment: or take a look at this [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/main/TodoListService/Web.config)

Comment: Sorry, It is the first time to use Owin for me. Is it okay that the breakpoint is not handled inside of the `Configuration` method?

Comment: I think it should ok for you to move the code to Startup file directly. You got any trouble on it?

Comment: I have a similar startup class as in the example https://imgur.com/a/GgXltDs. But this breakpoint wasn't handled for some reason. I wanted to debug it because this service returned 401 even if I left only Tenant in the configuration

Comment: I also checked that the JWT token exists in the request https://imgur.com/a/fluXPQm

Comment: Hi, I did a test in my side and it worked well. Could you pls check it?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't install Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb nuget and it was my mistake. After nuget installations, everything started working fine. I found this article useful as well https://wardwilmsen.com/2019/09/30/setup-test-and-debug-an-azure-ad-protected-web-api-asp-net/